# Allow content to overflow, but without stretching the viewport

Tags: html, css

I'm working on a header that's intended to overflow. It's got `white-space: nowrap` rule applied in order to prevent breaking the text into two or more lines.

The problem is, the viewport now stretches to fit the text and then the page is scrollable on the x-axis. Applying `overflow-x: hidden` hides the scrollbar, but it's still possible to scroll the page on mobile, and on desktop through middle mouse button drag.

I know I could use `position: fixed`, but that's not a solution for me. I want the header to stay where it is.

Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/axfmf7Lq/) with all my attempts so far.

Comment: So you are saying you *don't* want people to access the overflowing content?

Comment: That is correct. The header would be the same as the page title, so its content wouldn't practically be hidden or blocked.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, try applying this:

CSS:

```
.wrapper {
    position: absolute;
    width: 98%;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.text {
    font-size: 500%;
    white-space: nowrap;
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    float: left;
}
```

edit: oh, and remove overflow-x: hidden; from html,body